# PyScript: how can I fix the "JsException(TypeError: Failed to fetch)" error when trying to load a Python script from a separate file?

Tags: cors, pyscript

When trying to load a Python script from a separate file using PyScript, I get the following error:

```
JsException(TypeError: Failed to fetch)
```

How can I fix this error and run the Python script?

My source code consists of two files, hello.html and hello.py.

hello.html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello PyScript</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <py-env>
- paths:
  - /hello.py
  </py-env>
  <body>
    <py-script src="./hello.py"></py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

hello.py:

```py
print("Hello, PyScript!")
```

In the developer tools, the console displays the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'file:///hello.py' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

I am opening the file by double-clicking on it in file explorer.

Comment: It is not a Pyscript issue. It is a because a are running the file directly. You need a webserver like nginx, httpd or any othe for development stage

Comment: No, it's not a PyScript issue, at least not directly. But it does look like a PyScript issue to beginners, so I wrote this question and answer so that people would find this page when searching about their problem.

Comment: Indeed, it may be the first error that a Pyscript beginner may face !

Comment: This is a helpful question and answer - I don't believe it's a duplicate, as the canonical CORS answers for JavaScript won't mention PyScript, and so will be much harder to find.

Comment: @RichVel: Did you also have a CORS Issue? I got this introduced since today, already made an issue on Github. http.server did not solve it for me

Comment: The code above does need a local HTTP server for both the HTML file and `hello.py` to fix this CORS issue.  The [similar looking issue](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/360) that @DataMastery and I had with download of [pyscript.js](https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js) was actually unrelated to this - it was fixed by the PyScript project on 13th May, the same day it was reported.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because you are trying to load the file locally, using the `file` protocol scheme. (In other words, the URL of the page looks something like `file:///path/to/hello.html`.) When using the `file` protocol scheme, all major browsers disallow loading other files in the same folder [for security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp#loading_a_local_file). Instead, you need to [set up a local server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server) to host your files.

For example, you can set up a test server with Python by running the following command in the folder your files are in:

```
python -m http.server
```

(This assumes you have Python 3 installed, and the `python` command points to your Python 3 installation.)

Once you have started your local server with this command, you will be able to access hello.html at the URL http://localhost:8000/hello.html. When you access it this way, your browser will see that hello.html and hello.py both come from the same [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin), so it will allow you to load hello.py from hello.html.

Comment: but also i get the same error when i use:-
           <py-env>
                  - math
           </py-env>

Comment: @aymhenry The math module is in the standard library, so you should be able to use `import math` in a py-script tag without using a py-env tag.