# Can't reach a document with PyScript

Tags: python, html, pyscript

I want to reach a document, but I always get this error:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory: 'dbs/school/students.ini' )**

I've tried putting "/" or "./" before the dbs, but it doesn't work, so I want to know how can I reach that document, the dbs folder is in the same directory where I run the html.
The code I'm using works in python so I don't know why it doesn't work in PyScript

[Here is a picture of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb5Gr.png)

Comment: I believe you are encountering the problem with cross-origin loading? My understanding is that you need your file to be somewhere else on the web. Maybe put it at GitHub and use the URL? Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72122356/8508004). Or see [here](https://simonwillison.net/2022/May/4/datasette-lite/) for a very specific example dealing with loading something served with COS headers, which is unlikely to apply to your case but may help someone else.

Comment: Show the code that is accessing that file.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to add the file to your paths in your html code like:

```
    <py-env>
        - paths:
            - dbs/school/students.ini
    </py-env>
```

This way it should be added to your python environment.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, the solution i found was to insert my file into a github public branch and get the link from my github file, the code is below:

```
from pyodide.http import open_url
url_content = open_url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/')
```

to know more about it read

https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html

and see the videos from 1littlecoder about pyscript

https://www.youtube.com/c/1littlecoder